# How to check if someone is using my Windows Phone?

Tags: 8.0, security

My friend suspects that someone is using her phone. She changed her security code, but she is still afraid that it might be stolen again.

I was wondering if there's any built-in logging history or any 3rd party app which allows to see history of phone usage (what time someone unlocked lock screen etc.)?

In addition, is there way to set up two-step authentication for phone unlock? For example, after typing your security code, you have to type some another password, do face unlock, or whatever makes it harder to log in.

Comment: Is she concerned about any particular sort of usage? Is it just phone calls made, text messages sent, or app usage?

Comment: Reading text, facebook and email messages

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately with Windows Phone 8.1 your options are bascially limited to choosing a strong pin for your lockscreen - you can do more than 4 numbers.

Otherwise there's not much you can do as the system is quite locked down, therefore there are no keyloggers or similar tools to monitor your device.

You can check the task manager / app switcher (press and hold the back button) to see if any apps have been launched while you didn't have the phone with you. Just could close all apps manually before putting it down.

There are [a few apps in the store that can password-protect files](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/search?q=protect) like images and videos that you might want to take a look at.

When the phone is gone you can always try to track it / lock it / let it ring through the [Microsoft Devices](https://account.microsoft.com/devices) site.

Lastly I'd recommend posting your feature request onto the [Windows Phone UserVoice site](https://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions).

Answer (score 3):

Check out this app
[Screen Tracker on WP store](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/screen-tracker/702e04ef-8636-4c59-80ec-bd4e0004f162)
*for Windows Phone 8.1 only*

It's a tracking app that allow you to track how many times you check your phone a day.
It has good rating of 4.5/5 (171 reviews).
I hadn't tried as i have no need and its paid app also.

So give it a try, its not that costly.

*EDIT* 
Out of curiosity i tried this app and it works as it promises.
I left my phone at home and i came to know three time it was unlocked with exact time-stamp and how much time it was on each session.